# Mutate and Linear Model Functions

Tags: r, linear-regression, glm, mutate

I'm getting a linear model with glm() function using pielines. I want to add the result of the predict() into a new column, but I'm not able to use mutate() function because the glm() output is not a vector.

I already have the 5 results in a vector of the predict() function at the end of the pipelining.

```
diabetes %>%  
  rename(dpf = DiabetesPedigreeFunction) %>%
clean_names() %>%
glm(outcome ~ bmi + glucose + pregnancies + age,
      data = .,
      family = binomial()) %>%
      predict(newdata = data.frame(age =c(20,25,30,35,40),
                                   bmi = mean(diabetes$BMI),
                                   glucose = mean(diabetes$Glucose),
                                   pregnancies = mean(diabetes$Pregnancies)),
              type = "response")
```

The result with 5 ages entered is (I calculated the mean for the rest of the columns)

```
        1         2         3         4         5 
0.2618998 0.2745506 0.2875744 0.3009597 0.3146928
```

I want all the table with the prob column. I want to know how to do it using pipelines, it might be easier without pipelines.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that tidyverse pipelines that use the results objects from models need to use  functions from broom to put them into the form of a data frame.

Comment: Can you provide the `diabetes` dataset or a simpler version of it to help reproduce your issue?

Comment: @JamesAzam Of course, thanks, here it is: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13acDhnnuwTJGZGxOk7-e2zNKOdxvr1XZ?usp=share_link